# Is there any way to create View or temp table from dynamic SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that provides some data I want to save this data in a temp table or view. Please help

The query is given below:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#NLSPMTS3_tmp') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #NLSPMTS3_tmp

SELECT * 
INTO #NLSPMTS3_tmp 
FROM vwNLSPayments4

DECLARE @Columns AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(b.mop_fpd)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT mop_fpd FROM #NLSPMTS3_tmp) AS B
ORDER BY B.mop_fpd
 
-- You can't remove nulls from a PIVOT, so you have to create a second set of column names
DECLARE @NullColumns as VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @NullColumns =
       COALESCE(@NullColumns + ', ','') + 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(b.mop_fpd) + ', 0) ' + QUOTENAME(b.mop_fpd)
       FROM (Select DISTINCT mop_fpd FROM #NLSPMTS3_tmp) AS B
       ORDER BY B.mop_fpd
 
DECLARE @SQL as NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT acctrefno, ' + @NullColumns + '
                     FROM
                           (SELECT payment_amount, acctrefno, mop_fpd
                     FROM
                           nlsdev.dbo.vwnlsPayments2
                     ) as PivotData
                     PIVOT
                     (sum(payment_amount) FOR mop_fpd IN (' + @Columns + ')) AS PivotResult ORDER BY acctrefno'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

I just simply put create a view as `<above SQL query>` but it did not work.

Comment: Did you get an error? What do you mean it did not work?

Comment: You can simply put `CREATE VIEW NLSPMTS3_TMP AS` in front of your select, inside the dynamic sql.

Comment: Anything you can do with non-dynamic SQL you can do with dynamic SQL. Dynamic SQL is just SQL still; you're just using SQL to generate that statement and then run *that* SQL.

Comment: You can't define a view on a dynamic query like that. A view can only be a single static `select`. And a view doesn't "save" data, it's basically a query you can `select` from like a table. What are you actually trying to do? And why are you trying to do a dynamic pivot in SQL anyway, as opposed to pivoting in whatever UI or client app that you have? (@Larnu I think OP is trying to define the view as a dynamic pivot)

Comment: Possibly, @Charlieface . It's unclear what the OP really wants, I suppose. Putting a `CREATE VIEW`, in the dynamic statement would certainly create a view, provided the following statement is valid. If, however, the OP wants a `VIEW` that *creates* a dynamic pivot, then no they can't; but in truth that makes no sense and you would normally be filtering the results afterwards if you have a `VIEW`. That would be better off with a parametrised Stored Procedure for that.

Comment: @Larnu IMO a dynamic pivot doesn't ever make sense, but that's a different story :-)

Comment: There *are* uses for it, @Charlieface, but I do find they are more often due to design flaw that design requirement. Normally it should be something for the presentation layer, not the Database layer. But we are *way* off topic here. If we're even in a chat together, I am always up for talking about dynamic SQL though (as my website suggests ;) )

Comment: Basically, I want to create a view of the data which is returned by this part of the query.
DECLARE @Columns AS VARCHAR(MAX)
.....

Comment: Just put `CREATE VIEW dbo.YourViewsName AS ` prior to the `SELECT` ***inside*** your dynamic SQL then, @ShreyanshGokhru . Again, as I said, provided your dynamic SQL is valid it'll create a `VIEW` with a *static* definition.